# How can I install Android Studio and the Android SDK systemwide on a Linux system?

Tags: linux, installation

Android Studio *really* seems to prefer to behave like it's running on a single-user system.  Is there a good way to install it and the Android SDK on a Linux system in a way that minimizes the amount of per-user data it creates?

I've got a bunch of Fedora Linux client machines with hundreds of accounts.  The accounts have relatively-small disk quotas and the default way to run Android Studio ends up dropping 2-3 GB of data into each user's home directory, between the SDK and the AVD images.  I would like, if possible, to have Android Studio, the SDK, and the default AVD images installed centrally on each system (or, even better, on a NFS share that they all mount), in such a way that when a user starts Android Studio from the standard menu entry, everything just works without the user having to manually configure anything pertaining to the particulars of the system installation.

The systems that run Android Studio are all Fedora 23.  (The NFS server is Scientific Linux 6, but that shouldn't really matter.)

Comment: Hmm, looks tricky, as `studio.sh` hard-codes `$HOME`, though with luck you may be able to customize the `~/.AndroidStudio2.0/config/options` files to point to a shared `Android/Sdk` directory, unless the software assumes read/write to that directory...

Comment: I think the per-user config files would need to be read-write for the users so they could save genuinely individual preferences, like color schemes and so on.

Comment: Found detailed instructions at [this page](https://spremi.wordpress.com/2015/06/28/shared-android-studio-install-fedora/). Should help anyone reaching here for solution...

Answer (score 0):

All libraries required by Android Studio can be shared.

Open your Android Studio instance and go to:

```
File -> Project Structure
```

There you'll see on left pane "SDK Location" entry.
You can set there paths to:

- Android SDK location
- JDK location
- Android NDK location

Comment: That's something that each user would have to do individually, which means that I'd have to make sure each of our users read the documentation on "How to Set up Android Studio" beforehand.  With the number of people I've got (and the desire many of them will have to just start coding), I think that would be infeasible.  I'm looking for a solution that lets the users more or less just click on the menu entry and go, without having to worry about the data locations until they need something unusual.

Comment: @asciiphil use `skel` files that set defaults for the studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want user to manually setup Android Studio setup use skeleton files and create paths for users that links to shared folder.